Unmatched Route error- React Native with Expo Router
Here is the structure of my app folder

Here is my /(tabs)/_layout.js file


import React from "react";
import { Tabs } from "expo-router";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons"; // Import the icon library

const TabLayout = () => {
  return (
    <Tabs
      initialRouteName="home"
      screenOptions={{ tabBarStyle: { backgroundColor: "white" } }}
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="home"
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          title: "Home",
          backgroundColor: "white",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="home" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="explore"
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          title: "Explore",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="search" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="club"
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          title: "Club",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="people" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="settings"
        options={{
          headerShown: false,
          title: "Settings",
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <Ionicons name="ellipsis-horizontal" color={color} size={size} />
          ),
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default TabLayout;



I get this error in Expo Go whenever I first start it up
Unmatched route
Page could not be found. Go back.
exp://[IP address]/--/ 
sitemap

I can then go into the sitemap and see my app as intended. I want to make it go into the home tab by default. I've tried giving the <Tabs> element the initialRouteName="home" property and it still doesn't work. Let me know if you need any further details

You could perhaps look at using unstable_settings instead of specifying initial route on <Tabs
export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure any route can link back to `/`
  initialRouteName: 'home',
};

Found in the docs here
https://docs.expo.dev/router/advanced/router-settings/
